# Use of map function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to replicate [this analysis](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/06/10/is-seattle-really-seeing-an-uptick-in-cycling/) for my city.
I'm at the step where I copied and pasted the function to compute daily hours of daylight and add the aggregate count (weekly and daily) to the grouped dataset and then plot.

The thing is that I believe that the map function used here behave strangely (or something has changed along the pandas version). If I give for example `weekly.head()` the program returns in the hours_of_daylight column this output while I am expecting a number

```
            Total       East     West         daylight
Date                
2012-10-07  14292.0     7297.0   6995.0       <map object at 0x7f21afcc1ca0>
2012-10-14  16795.0     8679.0   8116.0       <map object at 0x7f21afcc1ca0>
2012-10-21  15509.0     7946.0   7563.0       <map object at 0x7f21afcc1ca0>
2012-10-28  13437.0     6901.0   6536.0       <map object at 0x7f21afcc1ca0>
2012-11-04  12194.0     6408.0   5786.0       <map object at 0x7f21afcc1ca0>
```

Of course, after this matplotlib says that there is not any numeric data to plot

The code is

```
daily = data.resample('d').sum()
weekly = data.resample('w').sum()


def hours_of_daylight(date, axis=23.44, latitude=47.61):
    """Compute the hours of daylight for the given date"""
    diff = date - pd.datetime(2000, 12, 21)
    day = diff.total_seconds() / 24. / 3600
    day %= 365.25
    m = 1. - np.tan(np.radians(latitude)) * np.tan(np.radians(axis) * np.cos(day * np.pi / 182.625))
    m = max(0, min(m, 2))
    return 24. * np.degrees(np.arccos(1 - m)) / 180.

# add this to our weekly data
weekly['daylight'] = map(hours_of_daylight, weekly.index)
daily['daylight'] = map(hours_of_daylight, daily.index)

weekly.head()
```

and, for the plot

```
weekly['daylight'].plot()
plt.ylabel('hours of daylight (Seattle)');
```

Can you help me understand what is wrong with these lines of code and get the effective number as result as well as the chart?

Comment: `map` is lazy in Python-3.x, so you do not *evaluate* the map object (unless forced to do so).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Index.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html):

```
weekly['daylight'] = weekly.index.map(hours_of_daylight)
print (weekly)
              Total    East    West   daylight
Date                                          
2012-10-07  14292.0  7297.0  6995.0  11.045208
2012-10-14  16795.0  8679.0  8116.0  10.644852
2012-10-21  15509.0  7946.0  7563.0  10.255305
2012-10-28  13437.0  6901.0  6536.0   9.881095
2012-11-04  12194.0  6408.0  5786.0   9.527645
```

---

```
daily['daylight'] = daily.index.map(hours_of_daylight)
```

Comment: Ok this one worked; can you tell me the difference between your code and mine? is it because of some deprecated pandas syntax?

Comment: @Ale - No, because `map` used in your solution is pure python [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function and in pandas it is `index.map` function. It is not same.

Comment: @Ale - Also is used [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for working with Series or columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can either try the .filter() function by providing specific details in the bracket or you can use the index.map() to get a structured DF.
I personally would recommend to go for .filter()